# Enviar documento pdf de mi API hecha en Django Rest Framework para descarga en cliente frontend

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Tengo una API Django rest framework y necesito cargar estos documentos por el administrador de Django

```
class FormatoManual(models.Model):
    nombre_formato = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name=_('nombre del formato'))
    formato = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/formatos_sa_manual/', verbose_name=_('formato'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Formato")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Formatos")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_formato
```

Y que desde el cliente se puede descargar según el nombre enviado en la petición del cliente.

```
url(r'^descargar_formato/(?P<nombre_formato>.+)/$', FormatoManualApiView.as_view(), name='sa.files.get')
```

Como puedo servir este archivo en mi API?

```
class FormatoManualApiView(views.APIView):

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, nombre_formato):
        try:
            from django.http import HttpResponse
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(nombre_formato)
            response.write(formato_sa)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            status_http = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            logger.error(e.__str__())
            data = {
                'status': status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                'error': e
            }
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status_http)
```

Esto es lo que he intentado pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma

```
class FormatoManualApiView(views.APIView):

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, nombre_formato):
        from django.http import FileResponse
        import traceback
        try:
            obj_formato = models.FormatoManual.objects.get(nombre_formato=nombre_formato)
            logger.info("Consultando documento: %s" % obj_formato.nombre_formato)
            response = FileResponse(obj_formato.formato, content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}.pdf"'.format(obj_formato.nombre_formato)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            status_http = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            logger.error(e.__str__())
            data = {
                'status': status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                'error': traceback.format_exc()
            }
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status_http)
```